# How to tell WPF UI thread that worker has finished its job?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, backgroundworker

Suppose i perform compute-bound task not in GUI thread but in a separate thread. I compute some data that reflects changes the user made in GUI. I need to have computed changes only for the last user action, so i need only one additional thread and cancel it every time user make new change.

How can i say nicely to GUI thread that computations in the worker thread are done? Is there some kind of callback or event, because use timer for the task isn't nice. Thanks.

EDIT: Also i investigated that to return some data from backgroundworker one just need to use Result field of DoWorkEventArgs.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`IProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface?

Comment: Why do you need to tell that to GUI thread? It's processing windows events, so you can use one of these (or a timer) to poll if worker has finished job. Otherwise create an event and rise that event at the end of worker job, subscribe to it in GUI thread, `invoke` if needed.

Comment: As @ScottNimrod answered, to perform something at the end of worker job you can run it (`Task`) asynchronously and simply `await` for it in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.Add following using: using System.ComponentModel;

1.Declare [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

2.Subscribe to events:

```
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

3.Implement two methods:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // run all background tasks here
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //update ui once worker complete his work
}
```

4.Run worker async whenever your need.

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```